# Constant expressions are not allowed in the ORDER BY clause in 90 or later compatibility modes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Upgrading a database from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2016. The Upgrade Advisor says I have a view that is giving me this problem:

> Object [dbo].[view_PHistory] uses a constant expression which are
>   not allowed in the ORDER BY clause in database compatibility level 90
>   or later.
>
> Constant expressions are allowed (and ignored) in the ORDER BY clause
>   when the database compatibility mode is set to 80 and earlier.
>   However, these expressions in the ORDER BY clause will cause the
>   statement to fail when the database compatibility mode is set to 90 or
>   later.
>
> Here is an example of such problematic statements:
>
> SELECT * FROM Production.Product ORDER BY CASE WHEN  1=2 THEN 3 ELSE 2
>   END"
>
> Before you change the database compatibility mode to 90 or later,
>   modify statements that use constant expressions in the ORDER BY clause
>   to use a column name or column alias, or a nonnegative integer
>   representing the position of the name or alias in the select list.

This is my view:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_PHistory]
AS
    SELECT  
        table1.SerialNo,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table1.SerialNo 
                           ORDER BY DATEADD(ms, table2.TimeStamp, table3.RegTime) DESC) AS LatestPoll    
    FROM    
        table1 
    INNER JOIN
        table2 ON table2.SerialNo = table1.SerialNo
               AND table2.Counted = 1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        table3 ON table3.scanID = table2.scanID
```

This view has no problem running on SQL Server 2014 whose compatibility level is 120.

When I swap the `ORDER BY DATEADD` function with a specific column name, the error prompt by the upgrade advisor goes away.

Moreover, I know the `DATEADD` function isn't returning a constant expression. I have no idea why this error is raised. I've been googling for the past 2 days.

Anyone care to illuminate me on this?

Thanks in advance. Much appreciated.

Edit: TimeStamp is int, RegTime is dateTime, e.g 2009-12-08 17:23:36.267

Comment: What if `table3.RegTime` is `NULL`? It's used in a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, you can't `ORDER BY NULL`.

Comment: Could you show definitions of table2.TimeStamp and table3.RegTime columns?

Comment: @Sergey Hi Sergey, TimeStamp is integer while RegTime is dateTime e.g 2009-12-08 17:23:36.267

Comment: It seems like just a some bug. I'd suggest to drop the view, upgrade database then create view again. If there will not be errors on creation then I'd throw it out of my head.

Comment: @Sergey I plan to upgrade anyway. I'll just have to run more tests after to make sure everything is in order. Will update post in due time.

Comment: I think it's because `AND table2.Counted = 1`, but I don't have on what to test now.

Comment: Are `TimeStamp` and `RegTime` unique columns in the result set? If so, what happens if you remove the table names from the references within the `DATEADD`? I suspect you're triggering a false positive from the rule that's meant to prevent you using aliases in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: They are not unique columns. Also, they are nullable. Just tried removing the table names from the references within the `DATEADD` and ran the upgrade advisor. Came back with the same errors. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `table3` and the use of `table3.RegTime` in the `ORDER BY` clause.
If `RegTime` is NULL, the expression will be a constant and cannot be evaluated.

Comment: I'm working on it together with Sergey's comments. Will update this post when I nail the problem. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a "constant" by any stretch of the imagination if it's something that can be evaluated differently for each row. Neither in common usage nor in any peculiarity of SQL Server phraseology.

Comment: Appreciate the comment. Could you elaborate in more layman terms? I'm not particularly very experienced in SQL. @Damien_The_Unbeliever